# Why does &object evaluate to two different values in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-address

Consider the following program:

```
#include <objc/nsobject.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function(NSObject** object) {
  printf("value of NSObject** in function: %p\n", object);
}

int main() {
  NSObject* object;
  printf("value of NSObject** in main:     %p\n", &object);
  function(&object);
}
```

Program output (compiled with `-fobjc-arc` on x86_64):

> `value of NSObject** in main:     0x7ffee1217668`
>   `value of NSObject** in function: 0x7ffee1217660`

Why are the values not equal? They're offset by 8 bytes, which I find unexpected. If I change it to a plain C type (e.g. `int**`) then they both print the same values. But double pointers to Objetive-C objects always give different values.

What's going on here, and why does `&object` evaluate to two different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC is creating an autoreleasing temporary object and passing the address of that and then, after `function` returns, assigning that to the strong `object` variable.

See [Ownership Inference: Indirect parameters](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters) to see why `function`'s parameter is inferred to be `__autoreleasing`. See [Passing to an out parameter by writeback](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#passing-to-an-out-parameter-by-writeback) to see why ARC creates the temporary.

I believe you could declare an explicit `__strong` qualifier on `function`'s parameter to avoid that.